# Android intents, close previous when opening next

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making an app for Android and I need some help. I have three activities **A**, **B** & **C**. When I'm in **A** and start **B**, I don't want to finish() **A** because I want the option to go back. But if I from **B** start **C** I want to finish both **A** and **B**. I've seen some examples using startActivityForResult but I never got the hang of it. Anyone have some easy sample to explain so I can use it in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, C.class );
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
startActivity( intent );
```

with that flag the activity stack is cleared, so when you press back button on C you will move to the home screen

Comment: But A doesn't finish when I press back in C

Answer (score 0):

For the first part
When u move form B to C you want to finish A and B
for this
StartActivityforResult from A and when you want to move from B to C finish B
it will automatically trigger onActivityResult of A, there you can start activity C

here is the example of StartActivityforResult

http://saiful103a.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/android-startactivity-and-startactivityforresult/

Answer (score 0):

> I have three intents A, B & C.

Just to be clear, I think you mean `Activity`s (you can't be "in" an `Intent`).

> When I'm in A and start B, I don't want to finish() A because I want the option to go back. But if I from B start C I want to finish both A and B.

What you want to do is call `startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, C.class), requestCode)` from `Activity B`. Then in `Activity B`, you override `onActivityResult()` and either `finish()` B (thus, popping `B` off the backstack) or you do nothing (thus, remaining in `B`).

Here's what you need to do:

1. Define a `public static final` request code in your class (this is considered good practice). You will use this code to distinguish between different calls to `startActivityForResult()` that you might make.

   ```
   public static final int C_START_CODE = 0;
   ```
2. From `Activity B`, call,

   startActivityForRequest(C.class, C_START_CODE);

   Then, catch the result in `B` by overriding `onActivityResult()` as follows,

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch(requestCode) {
           case C_START_CODE:
               if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   // Add code here as necessary before finishing B
                   //   and backing out of the Activity to A.
                   finish();
               }
           default: 
               break;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, when you decide to finish `Activity C`, make sure you distinguish between the two cases:

   - If you want to finish `Activity B` **AND** `Activity C`, call

     ```
     setResult(RESULT_OK);
     finish();
     ```
   - If you only want to finish `Activity C`, call

     ```
     setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
     finish();
     ```

Comment: Yes but how does A finish when I startActivity(this, C.class) ?

Comment: When I start C, I want A and B to finish.

Comment: In that case, you want to set the intent flag to be `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` when you call `startActivity(this, B.class);`